# Stretch a span across a td

Tags: html, css, html-table, tablerow

I think an image best describes this:  JS FIDDLE HERE: http://jsfiddle.net/fp2Ak/

[image]

What I want to do, is for those lines to actually touch. Each one is a span with a number in. within a td. Note: some Tds contain multiple spans, for example, 218 and 222. (you can see tr with faint blue lines.)

As you can see it does touch at one point, as this is the biggest element in the column (including header). But this is rarely the case. How would I stretch it to touch in ALL Cases.

You can suggest using someting other than span, but please note that I do need more than one thing in a td, and hence cant be applied to the td.

The CSS that governs most of this so far:

```
  table.Timetable td ,  table.Timetable th 
  {
      border-spacing: 0px;
      padding: 0px;
  }

  .bookingStart, .bookingMiddle, .bookingEnd
  {
      background-color: white;
      color: Black;
      border-top: 2px solid black;
        border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  }
  .bookingStart 
  {
      border-left: 2px solid black;
  }
    .bookingEnd
  {
      border-right: 2px solid black;
  }
```

Oh and preferabblly Id like to be able to pad the cells again, as the th clearly have been merged together.

JSfiddle of it here: http://jsfiddle.net/fp2Ak/

Comment: Providing a JSfiddle or something with sample HTML would be helpful, otherwise people have to manually write the HTML you already have.

Comment: Yes, great idea. Here : http://jsfiddle.net/fp2Ak/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

spans have to be floated in order to be affected by width, so you could do something like:

```
td span{float:left; width:100%; min-width:100%;}
```

or more accurately if I am understanding your css properly:

```
.bookingStart, .bookingMiddle, .bookingEnd
{
  background-color: white;
  color: Black;
  border-top: 2px solid black;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  float:left;
  width:100%;
  min-width:100%; /*some browsers like this better*/
}
```

Comment: though it would be very helpful to have some css / html to play with to make sure

Comment: jsfiddle.net/fp2Ak :)  I tried it and it is one step closer, but i get strange lines appearing else where.

Comment: ok well it looks like you have spans with the booking middle class that have no data, that might be why (since they now have width) I suggest removing those classes on ones you want empty

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fp2Ak/5/ There seems to be a slight offset when there are more than one in a td. Any ideas. ? :)

Comment: ok so it's because you have borders on some and not on others, so the border width is messing it up. Try adding &nbsp; to all the empty ones and adding td span{padding: 1px 0 1px 0;} above the .bookingStart, .bookingMiddle, .bookingEnd then adding padding:0; to your .bookingStart, .bookingMiddle, .bookingEnd{}.  So we're adding padding to all the spans to make up for the border, then overwriting that with 0 for the ones that have a border.  Hopefully that makes sense and of course, works ;)

Comment: actually it might be padding 2px 0 2px 0

Answer (score 2):

Your should put your borders on the td's not the spans. This will allow you to also put some padding on the td's to make even the long numbers look good.

Comment: I cant, as like i said, each td can/(and some do) contain more than number.

Comment: have you tired making the width of the span `100%` or a fixed width?

Comment: I have now, but doesnt change anything. :( try out the JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/fp2Ak/

Comment: if you add `display:block; width:100%` it works for me. You just have get rid of the border on unwanted spans

Comment: Using your method. I get offsets, as with the other method. Somewhat more due to bigger spacing between them. http://jsfiddle.net/fp2Ak/6/  any ideas? :)

Comment: Yup those are the 2 other divs you have in the td. if you get rid of the `bookingMiddle` class on the divs that have notihing in them you'll be all set

Comment: The idea behind those other spans /brs are to keep the same bookings inline.

Comment: since a your borders take up 2px so you need to apply a 2px padding to the other spans

Comment: Can you give me a working example please. I cant get it to work.